# Find most frequently reoccurring string in 1 file

Tags: linux, windows

Prologue:
We're given the assignment to implement a brainfuck interpreter as fast as possible. To make this interpreter as fast as possible, we want to make some brainfuck instructions like [-<+>] native to our interpreter. We want to do this with more instructions, so we wondered which instructions we should implement.

We found a lot of information about comparing two seperate files, but is there any way to find reoccurring strings within a file? For example:

file:

```
Hi, this is my text
also, it is an example of my question
```

Returns:

```
2 x ' is '
2 x ' my '
2 x ', '
```

Do you know of any program in Windows or Linux which can execute this?

Comment: Do you want to include spaces in strings? What are the delimiters?

Comment: Yes we want to include the spaces so no delimiters

Comment: And to which word should the spaces go? Left, right, both?

Comment: @jurez, I work with Maarten, the file should be viewed as a char array, so no distinction should be made between spaces, letters and numbers.

Comment: This is still ambiguous. Please provide a non-contradicting example of how a string should be broken into parts, or describe the exact rules.

Answer (score 0):

using sh, coreutils/sort and awk:

```
awk 'BEGIN { FS="[,. ;!?]" }  { for (i=1; i<=NF;i++) { A[$i]++ } }  END { for (a in A) { print A[a], a } }' | sort -k1 -n -r
```

you can customize delimiters in the FS variable.